# Expression cannot be a statement - Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, soql

The following code works fine. The Id variable that I see in my debug log when I execute the code is the correct 18 digit Id.

```
    List<Opportunity> psgPrimaryProjectIDToDelete = [Select pse__Primary_Project__c from Opportunity];
    System.debug('***************PSG Primary Project Name is ' + psgPrimaryProjectIDToDelete[0]);
    Id myId = psgPrimaryProjectIDToDelete[0].id;
        System.debug('***********myId = ' + myId);
```

The problem occurs when I try to use that Id variable to return a result in my select statement that follows it. I keep getting the error: Expression cannot be a statement.

I get that error when I follow my working code with this:

```
[Select Id from PSG_Vendor_Order__c where PSG_Project__c = :myId];
```

Or with this:

```
Set<Id> s = new Set<Id>();
s.add(myId);
[Select Id from PSG_Vendor_Order__c where PSG_Project__c in :s;
```

The error shows up on the select statement but I have no idea why.... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually build a new List you're not returning it correctly

```
List<PSG_Vendor_Order__c> psgVendorOrder = new List<PSG_Vendor_Order__c>([Select Id from PSG_Vendor_Order__c where PSG_Project__c = :myId]);
```

Comment: Thank you @EricSSH ! Such a simple answer to my question. I can't believe that I wasn't thinking about assigning the result to a variable..... I want to believe that the way the error was phrased was why I overlooked that!  I appreciate your quick reply!